# Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 300 seconds

Tags: tomcat6

I am getting

> Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 300 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.

this error while trying to start tomcat 6 in debug mode. Wherein I am able to start it in normal mode properly. I tried with increasing its timeout period, but no success. Could anyone rectify it???

Comment: One thing you can always do is to `tail -f` the logs during startup.

Comment: might be better off at serverfault.com :)

Comment: I am getting various NLS Missing message

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this kind of issue sometimes when I debug with Eclipse and Tomcat. Try to delete all your breakpoints and then restart Tomcat in debug mode.

Hope this will help people having same problem

Answer (score 0):

Change the all 3 port no means http, AJP and Tomcat admin port. then try it by restarting the tomcat server again.

Comment: its not working...i created new debug configuration using remote java application...and its working fine for me now....thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the server and select "Clean", and then "Publish", if there is something wrong with the server the error will be more especific when you use these options.